# SQL: Joining tables on primary key AND returning the primary key

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm writing a C# application and am using an Access .mdb. I have a table with email messages and a table with message relations (each email msg can be assigned to several teams of workers), so the rows in the relations table have "msgId" and "teamName" fields.

I want to to get all messages from the first table which are assigned to a specified team. I'm using the following query:

```
"SELECT * FROM Mails INNER JOIN MailAssignments ON Mails.msgId = MailAssignments.msgId"
```

But it doesn't return the msgId for me, I guess, because the tables are joined on this field, but then I
m not able to identify messages in my C# code.

How can I make the query return the msgId for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough specify the fields name in the selection, or add the table name where you want to get all the fields, try with this selection list :

```
SELECT Mails.* 
FROM Mails INNER JOIN MailAssignments 
ON Mails.msgId = MailAssignments.msgId
```

Answer (score 0):

It should appear **twice** in the resultset, for `Mails.msgId` and `MailAssignments.msgId` respectively.  However, you should not expect two columns named `msgId`. Rather, the DBMS should disambiguate the columns. This is a requirement of Standards SQL, BTW.

IIRC Access will rename **both** columns in order to disambiguate them. This would explain why there is no column named `msgId` in the result.